# Nested IF statement in ForEach-object loop

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm currently attempting to find out which members of a particular group have not logged into AD within the last 30 days. I've managed to return all users of the group but I'm having problems when piping this to a Foreach-object loop.

```powershell
import-module activedirectory

$DaysInactive = 30
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))

get-adgroupmember -identity "Remote Users" | foreach-object {
    if ($_.LastLogonDate -lt $time) {
        write-host $_.SamAccountName
    }
}
```

I think the problem is that I'm using an AD user attribute when calling LastLogonDate and as a result I receive an error saying that it is not recognised. 
I'm imagining that within the loop I need a `get-aduser` cmdlet but I'm unsure what to send as the value for `-filter`.

When PowerShell retrieves all members from the `get-adgroupmember` does it place the result set in an array? If so how can I retrieve the value of last logon date?

Comment: Should be: `if ($_.LastLogonDate -lt $time)`

Comment: Also, the .LastLogonDate property is not retrieved by default. You will need to take each of the items returned from Get-ADGroupMember and use Get-ADUser to explicitly get the .LastLogonDate property.

Comment: @EBGreen you're correct. Since applying arco444's suggestion it now returns all members without seeming to evaluate the conditional statement. What do I specify with Get-ADUser as I need to specify a filter?

Comment: Edit your question with your current code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Get-ADGroupMember -recursive -identity "Remote Desktop" |
    Where { $_.objectClass -eq "user" } |
    Get-ADUser -properties SamAccountName, LastLogonDate |
    Where { $_.LastLogonDate -lt $time } |
    select SamAccountName
```

- filter out groups
- i guess you want all nested members?
- load the LastLogonDate

Comment: Since you already have a pipeline I'd use `... | ? { $_.LastLogonDate -lt $time } | select -Expand SamAccountName` instead of the `ForEach-Object` loop with the nested `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I don't have the time to fully test this so it is off the cuff, but this should get you going in the right direction:

```
import-module activedirectory

$DaysInactive = 30
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))

$users = get-adgroupmember -identity "Remote Users"
foreach($user in $users){
    $lastLogin = (Get-ADUser $user -Property LastLogonDate).LastLogonDate
    if($lastLogin -lt $time){
        Write-Host $user.SamAccountName
    }
}
```

Comment: Converting a complicated pipe command into a more structured foreach loop like this is the way to go on this one. This way it is very clear what objects you are working with.